# Firefox extension: check if window is minimized

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm trying to keep track of the state of a Firefox window ("maximized", "minimized", "normal", "fullscreen"; see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMChromeWindow)). However, whatever I've tried, I never get to see the minimized event; the others doing fine. For example, if I add listeners to the window such as

```
window.addEventListener("activate", function(event) { dump("activate " + window.windowState + " " + window.screenX + " " + window.screenY + "\n"); }, false);
window.addEventListener("deactivate", function(event) { dump("deactivate " + window.windowState + " " + window.screenX + " " + window.screenY + "\n"); }, false);
window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) { dump("resize " + window.windowState + " " + window.screenX + " " + window.screenY + "\n"); }, false);
```

I never see 2 as the window.windowState (2 = STATE_MINIMIZED). I've tried a workaround using screenX and screenY, but that doesn't help. When I minimize the window the deactivate - not the resize - event fires with window.windowState being 3 (STATE_NORMAL) and the old screenX/screenY values.

Is there any way to detect when the Firefox window is being minimized? I'm at my wits' end.

Comment: I found a workaround using a timer that periodically checks the current window state, and then reports any changes. It's working, but I still don't understand what's the problem with the listener solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be listening to the [`sizemodechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Events#Window_events) event. That's the event firing after the window is minimized or maximized. The `resize` event doesn't fire for window minimization because technically the window isn't resized - it is hidden. And the `deactivate` event likely fires *before* the window is minimized, when it still has the normal state (I didn't check however).

Comment: Awesome! I missed that event completely. Thanks a lot!