# Browser window minimize/maximize event

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox extension: check if window is minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767068/firefox-extension-check-if-window-is-minimized)

I've written a Firefox extension that need to be notified whenever you minimize/restore the browser window. What JavaScript event browser fires when you minimize/restore browser window?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767068/firefox-extension-check-if-window-is-minimized See here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [sizemodechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Events#Window_events) event, available in Firefox 8 and above. Note that you need to check whether `window.windowState` really changed, before Firefox 12 this event might fire during a regular resize.