# How to track Window Minimization/Maximization using Addon SDK?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, dom-events

How can I determine when a window is minimized and revoked (maximized) using `Addon SDK`?

Apparently I am calculating the user browsing time so I need to start and stop a timer on window maximization and minimization respectively.

I want to do it from the Addon Code itself, and not by message passing from Content Script after OnBlur event because that is too unreliable.

I think something like this is on the cards: [Firefox extension: check if window is minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767068/firefox-extension-check-if-window-is-minimized)

But I don't know how to use XPCOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the base window using the window-utils module from api-kit:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/api-utils/window-utils.html

In particular, I think you'll be using the WindowTracker object.