# Is there an HTML on page activated like event or functional workaround to achieve the same?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA (progressive web app) application that is meant to be “installed” by the user. For the most part, everything works pretty good except for one small problem. The problem is that when the application is minimized (not closed), the data becomes stale after a while and ideally, I would like to automatically refresh the information when the user pulls up the app back again.

After some research, I don’t seem to be able to find an event on the HTML element that would trigger when the page is activated (when the user pulls the app up). If such an event existed, I would use that event to run some code that would fetch the latest and greatest information from the server and sync up the user interface info, or at the very least, run some code that automatically makes a call to refresh the page.

By the way, I tried looking into technologies such as websockets and server-sent events to maintain the user interface data up to date but that gets kind of complicated and even if I get that to work, looks like I will end up having to deal with all kinds of disconnect issues which puts me back on square one.

So my question is, what would be the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Dunno about PWAs but with a normal web page you can check if it's currently visible or not and act on that. I think there might even be an event for that.

Comment: are you using anything like react or angular? that might help to know where to put the focus events

Comment: [more on page visibility, in case it helps](https://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-detect-when-page-is-not-visible-using-javascript.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox extension: check if window is minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767068/firefox-extension-check-if-window-is-minimized)

Comment: onfocus also exists in pure javascript webapplications

Comment: "... looking into technologies such as websockets and server-sent events..." ajax is the place to get started. I myself just used this for the first time a month or two ago, and it was shockingly easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Use the visibilitychange event: -

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", visibilityChange);
```

For a complete working example see the [BackgroundGeolocation solution.](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen/blob/master/TravelManager.html)

If you want to get more adventurous or "better" then you could use the Cache API with a ServiceWorker and then satisfy your Fetch request from Cache (where possible) whilst simultaneously asking the server for a fresh copy for the "next" query.

IMHO, the best way to replicate data is "**Not at all!**". But then the nature of my Apps renders them as useful as teats on a bull without a network. Also we have 5G wireless being installed as we speak. I'll let Jake look after mid-Saharan Africa.